# In Linux initrd image, ethernet fails to work

Tags: linux, filesystems, ethernet, initrd

I am working on SABRE SD Development board, which uses i.Mx6 Quad core processor.  I have developed a initrd image for this board.  The kernel boots up and the initrd images is mounted successfully. Even the fec ethernet drivers are loaded properly.

But during the init process the dhcp fails to designate an ip for the ethernet device.

on analysis using the strace utility on the 'dhcp' command the following log was obtained:
In the log a select system call Timeouts causing the error. A selective portion of the log is given bellow.

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 6

ioctl(6, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_index=2}) = 0

ioctl(6, SIOCGIFHWADDR, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_hwaddr=00:04:9f:02:b3:81}) = 0

close(6)                                = 0

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {53, 815520338}) = 0

write(1, "Sending discover...\n", 20Sending discover...
)   = 20

socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 8)        = 6

bind(6, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x800, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(6)={0, 
ffffffffffff}, 20) = 0

sendto(6, "E\0\0014\0\0\0\0@\21y\272\0\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\0D\0C\1 ,h\1\1\6\0"..., 308, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x800, if2, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, add8

close(6)                                = 0

fcntl64(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {53, 990583005}) = 0

select(6, [3 5], NULL, NULL, {3, 0})    = 0 (Timeout)
```

But when the same rootfs used in initrd image is used with SD card boot the dhcp command does not fail.

Can any one help me with some clues?

with regards,

Vivek

Comment: Make sure your network driver load before dhcp discovery.

Comment: Hi Satish, the network driver is loaded properly and when i plugin the the network cable i am able to see the link up message from the driver.

Comment: Hi, how do you setup init process (in the initrd) for DHCP? I have to do the same. If you put it on the command, some people will get help.